# Find closest id using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

im trying to get the closest id whena button is clicked to send it in an ajax request. But ive been struggling achiving so.

The HTML part is this one (cshtml)

```
                            <div id="modifyCar_@car.Id" class="modifyCar">
                                <!--Delete car button-->
                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bg-danger" id="btnDeleteCar" name="btnDeleteCar">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

im trying to extract the **@car.Id** part

The JS part is this:

```
id: $(this).closest("div").find(".modifyCar").attr("id"),
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique. You don't need to find the closest one - - there should only be one with that `id`.

Comment: Did you mean `.closest(".modifyCar")`? Also, using IDs for storing data is discouraged. IDs really should be used for fixed, static, unique elements. For arbitrary data, use custom [`data-` _*_ attributes](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead. E.g. use the attribute `data-modify-car-id="@car.Id"`. Then `$(this).closest("[data-modify-car-id]").data("modifyCarId")`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the ids are generated in a foreachloop, its not just one, im trying to find the correct one in the row where i pressed the button

Comment: Then, you should be looking for the closest `div` with a class of `modifyCar` as @SebastianSimon wrote.

Comment: `the ids are generated in a foreachloop` that's a code smell. `im trying to find the correct one in the row where i pressed the button` in this case change `.find('div').find('.modifyCar')` to `.closest('.modifyCar')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes finaly i got it to work with ur solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var myId = $(this).closest(".modifyCar").attr("id");
    console.log(myId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modifyCar_@car.Id" class="modifyCar">
  <!--Delete car button-->
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bg-danger" id="btnDeleteCar" name="btnDeleteCar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.closest()` can accept a selector, like a Class name. Your Code will stop at the Parent DIV Element, as that matches the closest `"div"` selector.